# Window scrolling after start-process and pop-to-buffer

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to write a function that compiles some code, and if the compilation succeeds, it spawns the process and opens its output in a new window. The compilation bit works fine, but there's something weird going on with the second part. I wrote some code that looks like this:

```
(defun test-function ()
  (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*output*")
    (erase-buffer)
    (start-process "echo" (current-buffer) "echo" "hi")
    (pop-to-buffer (current-buffer))))
```

This code almost works, but when it runs, the top of the screen seems to sit right below the actual output of the program. So, once `echo` quits, the screen looks like

```
Process echo finished
```

And scrolling up one line gives (the expected)

```
blah

Process echo finished
```

Is there a way to get it to start at the actual top of the buffer? I've tried things like `scroll-up` and `goto-char` before and after starting the process, but they don't seem to affect anything. From some other sources, it seems like I could attach a sentinel to the process and have it scroll up when there's output, but that seems like overkill just to scroll up at the beginning.

Comment: `scroll-up` and `goto-char` are not helping because `start-process` works asynchronously: process is started and function call returns typically before any process had the chance to write anything into the buffer.  IMHO a sentinel that moves the point to the beginning upon process finish state change is not overkill, but a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a hack, but for me this works:

```
(insert "\n")
(start-process ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an `\n` before `Process` built into `process.c`.  Perhaps someone can suggest for you how to modify this after Emacs has already been built  --  if not, a custom build seems like an extreme solution.

Of course, you could use elisp code to go up and delete the hard return after the fact.

```
Searching 5342 files for "\nprocess"

/Users/HOME/Desktop/emacs-trunk/src/process.c:
 6405        tem = BVAR (current_buffer, read_only);
 6406        bset_read_only (current_buffer, Qnil);
 6407:       insert_string ("\nProcess ");
 6408        { /* FIXME: temporary kludge.  */
 6409   Lisp_Object tem2 = p->name; Finsert (1, &tem2); }

/Users/HOME/Desktop/emacs-trunk/lisp/man.el:
 1304                      (substring msg 0 eos) msg))))
 1305              (goto-char (point-max))
 1306:             (insert (format "\nprocess %s" msg))))
 1307        ))
 1308          (if delete-buff

/Users/HOME/Desktop/emacs-trunk/lisp/progmodes/sql.el:
 3944    (if (and (eq (current-buffer) sql-buffer)
 3945      (not buffer-read-only))
 3946:       (insert (format "\nProcess %s %s\n" process event))
 3947      (message "Process %s %s" process event)))
 3948  

/Users/HOME/Desktop/emacs-trunk/lisp/shell.el:
  641      (when (buffer-live-p buf)
  642        (with-current-buffer buf
  643:         (insert (format "\nProcess %s %s\n" process event))))))
  644  
  645  ;;;###autoload

4 matches across 4 files
```

Comment: Is it that newline that's causing the problem? Even without the newline, it still wouldn't be showing the "blah", it would just show "Process echo finished" without the empty line.

Comment: My guess is that there is a `\n` after `blah` (probably also defined in `process.c`), and another `\n` before `Process` as indicated above.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't understand why the newlines would cause the window to sit at that specific position.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing the issue -- perhaps by adding a screenshot to your question, either I or someone else might be able to further assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing it with a process sentinel:

```
(defun recenter-temp-buffer (process event)
  (pop-to-buffer (process-buffer process)) (recenter-top-bottom))

(with-output-to-temp-buffer "test-buffer"
  (set-process-sentinel 
    (start-process "test-process" "test-buffer" "echo" "hello") 
                   'recenter-temp-buffer))
```

Note that the sentinel will call `(recenter-top-bottom)` on every status change, which may not be what you want.